# Monotouch: how to register a Custom Event in my custom UIView so it can shows in the iOS Designer?

Tags: ios, events, uiview, attributes, xamarin.ios

I have a custom UI component class derived from a simple UIView.
The custom component is displayed correctly in the iOS Designer (Xamarin Studio), but the custom events I've created in the component are not displayed in the events tab of the designer, so I cannot subscribe or connect to my event. 
Do I need to add some special attribute to the event declaration to be recognized by the iOS Designer?

```
 [Register("Foo")]
 public class Foo : UIView
 {

    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

   public void DoSomething()
   {
     // do stuff

     // raise the MyEvent event
     var handler = MyEvent;
     if (handler != null)
     {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Not sure that's possible with events, but have you tried decorating your event with `[Export("MyEvent"), Browsable(true)]`? Check out http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/ and http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/

Comment: have you found a solution ? thx